# When to use ' (or quote) in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, quote

After making it through the major parts of an introductory Lisp book, I still couldn't understand what the special operator `(quote)` (or equivalent `'`) function does, yet this has been all over Lisp code that I've seen.

What does it do?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

**Short answer**
Bypass the default evaluation rules and do *not* evaluate the expression (symbol or s-exp), passing it along to the function exactly as typed.

**Long Answer: The Default Evaluation Rule**

When a regular (I'll come to that later) function is invoked, all arguments passed to it are evaluated. This means you can write this:

```
(* (+ a 2)
   3)
```

Which in turn evaluates `(+ a 2)`, by evaluating `a` and 2. The value of the symbol `a` is looked up in the current variable binding set, and then replaced.  Say `a` is currently bound to the value 3:

```
(let ((a 3))
  (* (+ a 2)
     3))
```

We'd get `(+ 3 2)`, + is then invoked on 3 and 2 yielding 5.  Our original form is now `(* 5 3)` yielding 15.

**Explain `quote` Already!**

Alright. As seen above, all arguments to a function are evaluated, so if you would like to pass the *symbol* `a` and not its value, you don't want to evaluate it.  Lisp symbols can double both as their values, and markers where you in other languages would have used strings, such as keys to hash tables.

This is where `quote` comes in.  Say you want to plot resource allocations from a Python application, but rather do the plotting in Lisp.  Have your Python app do something like this:

```py
print("'(")
while allocating:
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        print(f"(allocate {random.randint(0, 20)})")
    else:
        print(f"(free {random.randint(0, 20)})")
    ...
print(")")
```

Giving you output looking like this (slightly prettyfied):

```
'((allocate 3)
  (allocate 7)
  (free 14)
  (allocate 19)
  ...)
```

Remember what I said about `quote` ("tick") causing the default rule not to apply? Good. What would otherwise happen is that the values of `allocate` and `free` are looked up, and we don't want that.  In our Lisp, we wish to do:

```
(dolist (entry allocation-log)
  (case (first entry)
    (allocate (plot-allocation (second entry)))
    (free (plot-free (second entry)))))
```

For the data given above, the following sequence of function calls would have been made:

```
(plot-allocation 3)
(plot-allocation 7)
(plot-free 14)
(plot-allocation 19)
```

**But What About `list`?**

Well, sometimes you *do* want to evaluate the arguments.  Say you have a nifty function manipulating a number and a string and returning a list of the resulting ... things.  Let's make a false start:

```
(defun mess-with (number string)
  '(value-of-number (1+ number) something-with-string (length string)))

Lisp> (mess-with 20 "foo")
(VALUE-OF-NUMBER (1+ NUMBER) SOMETHING-WITH-STRING (LENGTH STRING))
```

Hey! That's not what we wanted.  We want to *selectively* evaluate some arguments, and leave the others as symbols. Try #2!

```
(defun mess-with (number string)
  (list 'value-of-number (1+ number) 'something-with-string (length string)))

Lisp> (mess-with 20 "foo")
(VALUE-OF-NUMBER 21 SOMETHING-WITH-STRING 3)
```

**Not Just `quote`, But `backquote`**

Much better!  Incidently, this pattern is so common in (mostly) macros, that there is special syntax for doing just that. The backquote:

```
(defun mess-with (number string)
  `(value-of-number ,(1+ number) something-with-string ,(length string)))
```

It's like using `quote`, but with the option to explicitly evaluate some arguments by prefixing them with comma.  The result is equivalent to using `list`, but if you're generating code from a macro you often only want to evaluate small parts of the code returned, so the backquote is more suited.  For shorter lists, `list` can be more readable.

**Hey, You Forgot About `quote`!**

So, where does this leave us? Oh right, what does `quote` actually do? It simply returns its argument(s) unevaluated!  Remember what I said in the beginning about regular functions?   Turns out that some operators/functions need to *not* evaluate their arguments.  Such as IF -- you wouldn't want the else branch to be evaluated if it wasn't taken, right?  So-called *special operators*, together with macros, work like that. Special operators are also the "axiom" of the language -- minimal set of rules -- upon which you can implement the rest of Lisp by combining them together in different ways.

Back to `quote`, though:

```
Lisp> (quote spiffy-symbol)
SPIFFY-SYMBOL

Lisp> 'spiffy-symbol ; ' is just a shorthand ("reader macro"), as shown above
SPIFFY-SYMBOL
```

Compare to (on Steel-Bank Common Lisp):

```
Lisp> spiffy-symbol
debugger invoked on a UNBOUND-VARIABLE in thread #<THREAD "initial thread" RUNNING   {A69F6A9}>:
  The variable SPIFFY-SYMBOL is unbound.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:QUIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV SPIFFY-SYMBOL #<NULL-LEXENV>)
0]
```

Because there is no `spiffy-symbol` in the current scope!

**Summing Up**

`quote`, `backquote` (with comma), and `list` are some of the tools you use to create lists, that are not only lists of values, but as you seen can be used as lightweight (no need to define a `struct`) data structures!

If you wish to learn more, I recommend Peter Seibel's book [Practical Common Lisp](http://gigamonkeys.com/book) for a practical approach to learning Lisp, if you're already into programming at large. Eventually on your Lisp journey, you'll start using packages too. Ron Garret's [The Idiot's Guide to Common Lisp Packages](http://www.flownet.com/ron/packages.pdf) will give you good explanation of those.

Happy hacking!

Comment: In my emacs SBCL is setup and when I type `  'this 'is 'true `  It returns only last i.e TRUE in output. Even in portacle I'm getting same output

Comment: @Totoro The return value of a function or just multiple statements in lisp is the last expression, so it actually returns `this`, then `is`, then `true`, but you only see the last one returned. (this is and true are separate statements)

Answer (score 57):

It says "don't evaluate me".  For example, if you wanted to use a list as data, and not as code, you'd put a quote in front of it.  For example,

`(print '(+ 3 4))` prints "(+ 3 4)", whereas
`(print (+ 3 4))` prints "7"

Comment: How might evaluate it then for example is there an `unquote` command?

Comment: @William Lisps have a convenient function called `eval`: `(print (eval '(+ 3 4)))`.  This is what makes Lisps so great: lists are code, and code is lists, so a Lisp program can manipulate itself.

Answer (score 20):

Other people have answered this question admirably, and Matthias Benkard brings up an excellent warning.

DO NOT USE QUOTE TO CREATE LISTS THAT YOU WILL LATER MODIFY.  The spec allows the compiler to treat quoted lists as constants.  Often, a compiler will optimize constants by creating a single value for them in memory and then referencing that single value from all locations where the constant appears.  In other words, it may treat the constant like an anonymous global variable.

This can cause obvious problems.  If you modify a constant, it may very well modify other uses of the same constant in completely unrelated code.  For example, you may compare some variable to '(1 1) in some function, and in a completely different function, start a list with '(1 1) and then add more stuff to it.  Upon running these functions, you may find that the first function doesn't match things properly anymore, because it's now trying to compare the variable to '(1 1 2 3 5 8 13), which is what the second function returned.  These two functions are completely unrelated, but they have an effect on each other because of the use of constants.  Even crazier bad effects can happen, like a perfectly normal list iteration suddenly infinite looping.

Use quote when you need a constant list, such as for comparison.  Use list when you will be modifying the result.

Comment: So it sounds like you should use `(list (+ 1 2))`  most of the time.  If so how do you prevent the evaluation of `(+ 1 2)` inside such an example?  Is there an `unquote` command?

Comment: Do you want the equivalent of `'((3))`, or the equivalent of `'((+ 1 2))`? If the latter, you have to use more `list`: `(list (list '+ 1 2))`.  Or if you wanted the equivalent of `'(+ 1 2)`, just `(list '+ 1 2)`.  And remember, if you're not modifying the list, feel free to use quote: nothing wrong with `'(+ 1 2)` if you're just comparing against it or something.

Comment: Do you mind referencing where quoted lists are supposed to be treated as constants?

Comment: The HyperSpec http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm says behavior is undefined if the quoted object is destructively modified. It's implied that this is to allow impls to treat the values as atomic values.

Answer (score 14):

One answer to this question says that QUOTE “creates list data structures”.  This isn't quite right.  QUOTE is more fundamental than this.  In fact, QUOTE is a trivial operator: Its purpose is to *prevent* anything from happening at all.  In particular, it doesn't create anything.

What (QUOTE X) says is basically “don't do anything, just give me X.”  X needn't be a list as in (QUOTE (A B C)) or a symbol as in (QUOTE FOO).  It can be any object whatever.  Indeed, the result of evaluating the list that is produced by (LIST 'QUOTE SOME-OBJECT) will always just return SOME-OBJECT, whatever it is.

Now, the reason that (QUOTE (A B C)) seems as if it created a list whose elements are A, B, and C is that such a list really is what it returns; but at the time the QUOTE form is evaluated, the list has generally already been in existence for a while (as a component of the QUOTE form!), created either by the loader or the reader prior to execution of the code.

One implication of this that tends to trip up newbies fairly often is that it's very unwise to modify a list returned by a QUOTE form.  Data returned by QUOTE is, for all intents and purposes, to be considered as part of the *code* being executed and should therefore be treated as read-only!

Answer (score 11):

The quote prevents execution or evaluation of a form, turning it instead into data.  In general you can execute the data by then eval'ing it.

quote creates list data structures, for example, the following are equivalent:

```
(quote a)
'a
```

It can also be used to create lists (or trees):

```
(quote (1 2 3))
'(1 2 3)
```

You're probably best off getting an introductary book on lisp, such as [Practical Common Lisp](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/) (which is available to read on-line).

Answer (score 3):

**In Emacs Lisp:**

**What can be quoted ?**

Lists and symbols.

Quoting a number evaluates to the number itself:
`'5` is the same as `5`.

**What happens when you quote lists ?**

For example:

`'(one two)` evaluates to

`(list 'one 'two)` which evaluates to

`(list (intern "one") (intern ("two")))`.

`(intern "one")` creates a symbol named "one" and stores it in a "central" hash-map, so anytime you say `'one` then the symbol named `"one"` will be looked up in that central hash-map.

**But what is a symbol ?**

For example, in OO-languages (Java/Javascript/Python) a symbol could be represented as an object that has a `name` field, which is the symbol's name like `"one"` above, and data and/or code can be associated with it this object.

So an symbol in Python could be implemented as:

```
class Symbol:
   def __init__(self,name,code,value):
       self.name=name
       self.code=code
       self.value=value
```

In Emacs Lisp for example a symbol can have 1) data associated with it AND (at the same time - for the same symbol) 2) code associated with it - depending on the context, either the data or the code gets called.

For example, in Elisp:

```
(progn
  (fset 'add '+ )
  (set 'add 2)
  (add add add)
)
```

evaluates to `4`.

Because `(add add add)` evaluates as:

```
(add add add)
(+ add add)
(+ 2 add)
(+ 2 2)
4
```

So, for example, using the `Symbol` class we defined in Python above, this `add` ELisp-Symbol could be written in Python as `Symbol("add",(lambda x,y: x+y),2)`.

Many thanks for folks on IRC #emacs for explaining symbols and quotes to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
Code is data and data is code.  There is no clear distinction between them.
```

This is a classical statement any lisp programmer knows.

When you quote a code, that code will be data.

```
1 ]=> '(+ 2 3 4)
;Value: (+ 2 3 4)

1 ]=> (+ 2 3 4)
;Value: 9
```

When you quote a code, the result will be data that represent that code.  So, when you want to work with data that represents a program you quote that program.  This is also valid for atomic expressions, not only for lists:

```
1 ]=> 'code
;Value: code

1 ]=> '10
;Value: 10

1 ]=> '"ok"
;Value: "ok"

1 ]=> code
;Unbound variable: code
```

Supposing you want to create a programming language embedded in lisp -- you will work with programs that are quoted in scheme (like `'(+ 2 3)`) and that are interpreted as code in the language you create, by giving programs a semantic interpretation.  In this case you need to use quote to keep the data, otherwise it will be evaluated in external language.

Answer (score 2):

When we want to pass an argument itself instead of passing the value of the argument then we use quote. It is mostly related to the procedure passing during using lists, pairs and atoms
which are not available in C programming Language ( most people start programming using C programming, Hence we get confused) 
This is code in Scheme programming language which is a dialect of lisp and I guess you can understand this code.

```
(define atom?              ; defining a procedure atom?
  (lambda (x)              ; which as one argument x
(and (not (null? x)) (not(pair? x) )))) ; checks if the argument is atom or not
(atom? '(a b c)) ; since it is a list it is false #f
```

The last line (atom? 'abc) is passing abc as it is to the procedure to check if abc is an atom or not, but when you pass(atom? abc) then it checks for the value of abc and passses the value to it. Since, we haven't provided any value to it

Answer (score 2):

Quote returns the internal representation of its arguments.  After plowing through way too many explanations of what quote *doesn't* do, that's when the light-bulb went on.  If the REPL didn't convert function names to UPPER-CASE when I quoted them, it might not have dawned on me.

So.  Ordinary Lisp functions convert their arguments into an internal representation, evaluate the arguments, and apply the function.  Quote converts its arguments to an internal representation, and just returns that.  Technically it's correct to say that quote says, "don't evaluate", but when I was trying to understand what it did, telling me what it doesn't do was frustrating.  My toaster doesn't evaluate Lisp functions either; but that's not how you explain what a toaster does.

Answer (score 2):

**Anoter short answer:**

`quote` means without evaluating it, and *backquote* is quote but leave *back doors*.

**A good referrence:**

Emacs Lisp Reference Manual make it very clear

9.3 Quoting

The special form quote returns its single argument, as written, without evaluating it. This provides a way to include constant symbols and lists, which are not self-evaluating objects, in a program. (It is not necessary to quote self-evaluating objects such as numbers, strings, and vectors.)

Special Form: quote object

```
This special form returns object, without evaluating it.
```

Because quote is used so often in programs, Lisp provides a convenient read syntax for it. An apostrophe character (‘'’) followed by a Lisp object (in read syntax) expands to a list whose first element is quote, and whose second element is the object. Thus, the read syntax 'x is an abbreviation for (quote x).

Here are some examples of expressions that use quote:

```
(quote (+ 1 2))
     ⇒ (+ 1 2)

(quote foo)
     ⇒ foo

'foo
     ⇒ foo

''foo
     ⇒ (quote foo)

'(quote foo)
     ⇒ (quote foo)
```

9.4 Backquote

Backquote constructs allow you to quote a list, but selectively evaluate elements of that list. In the simplest case, it is identical to the special form quote (described in the previous section; see Quoting). For example, these two forms yield identical results:

```
`(a list of (+ 2 3) elements)
     ⇒ (a list of (+ 2 3) elements)

'(a list of (+ 2 3) elements)
     ⇒ (a list of (+ 2 3) elements)
```

The special marker ‘,’ inside of the argument to backquote indicates a value that isn’t constant. The Emacs Lisp evaluator evaluates the argument of ‘,’, and puts the value in the list structure:

```
`(a list of ,(+ 2 3) elements)
     ⇒ (a list of 5 elements)
```

Substitution with ‘,’ is allowed at deeper levels of the list structure also. For example:

```
`(1 2 (3 ,(+ 4 5)))
     ⇒ (1 2 (3 9))
```

You can also splice an evaluated value into the resulting list, using the special marker ‘,@’. The elements of the spliced list become elements at the same level as the other elements of the resulting list. The equivalent code without using ‘`’ is often unreadable. Here are some examples:

```
(setq some-list '(2 3))
     ⇒ (2 3)

(cons 1 (append some-list '(4) some-list))
     ⇒ (1 2 3 4 2 3)

`(1 ,@some-list 4 ,@some-list)
     ⇒ (1 2 3 4 2 3)
```