# What is ' (apostrophe) in Racket?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, quote, repl-printed-representation

I am a little confused about the meaning of the `'` sign in racket. It appears to me that the same sign has different meanings. Look at 2 simple examples below:

[`list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=list#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list%29%29)

> Returns a newly allocated list containing the vs as its elements.

```
> (list 1 2 3 4)
'(1 2 3 4)
```

[`quote`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quote.html?q=quote#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._quote%29%29)

> Produces a constant value corresponding to *datum* (i.e., the representation of the program fragment) without its lexical information, source location, etc. Quoted pairs, vectors, and boxes are immutable.

```
> '(1 2 3 4)
'(1 2 3 4)
```

So my question is: 
Does the `'` sign has 2 meanings (a *symbol* and a *list*) or are these the same data type and `list` actually returns a *quoted constant value*? If the second is the case why does this work:

```
> '(+ (- 2 13) 11)
'(+ (- 2 13) 11)

> (eval (list + (- 2 13) 11))
0
```

(also `(eval '(+ (- 2 13) 11))`  works and evaluates correctly to `0`)

But this does not:

```
> (list + (- 2 13) 11)
'(#<procedure:+> -11 11)

> (eval '(#<procedure:+> -11 11))
. read: bad syntax `#<'
```

Related maybe:
[What is ' (apostrophe) in Lisp / Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539144/what-is-apostrophe-in-lisp-scheme)

Comment: The reason `(eval '(#<procedure:+> -11 11))` doesn't work is that `#<procedure:+>` cannot be read back in. However, using quasiquote and unquote, `(eval (quasiquote ((unquote +) -11 11)))` works. Using the short hand that would be written as ``(eval `(,+ -11 11))``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>` is a sign of REPL - the Read-Eval-Print Loop.

First, whatever expression you've typed at the REPL prompt is *read* - converted to some internal abstract syntax tree representation. Then this internal representation of the typed-in expression is *evaluated* - i.e. its value is found. Then the result is printed.

When we type

```
> (list 1 2 3 4)
```

the typed-in expression is read as a nested structure, let's write it as

```
[LIST | [1 | [2 | [3 | [4 | NIL ]]]]]
```

according to the usual representation of lists as pairs of data and the rest of the list (here showing a pair of `a` and `b` as `[a | b]`).

Then the above structure is evaluated, and because its first element was `LIST` it causes the invocation of `list` with the arguments as specified, which causes a fresh list structure to be built, which can be represented as

```
[1 | [2 | [3 | [4 | NIL ]]]]
```

Then it is printed, usually as `(1 2 3 4)` but Racket chooses to print it as `'(1 2 3 4)`. Incidentally, it can't be evaluated, because `1` can not be *called*.

Next, the quoted expression `'(1 2 3 4)`, which is read as `(quote (1 2 3 4))`. It is converted into

```
[QUOTE | [ [1 | [2 | [3 | [4 | NIL ]]]] | NIL ]]
```

which, when evaluated (according to the evaluation rule for `quote`), returns the *data* it received. Which we represent as

```
[1 | [2 | [3 | [4 | NIL ]]]]
```

That's why the two are similar. Whether we build a new list containing 1, 2, 3, and 4; or we cause it to be created as part of *read* process, so it gets returned verbatim by `quote`; the result is the same.

Comment: thank you for clarification. I think in combination with the previous answer I finally got it :)

Comment: you're most welcome. :) some claim this is the most confusing part of Scheme. Besides the call/cc of course. :)

Answer (score 7):

You are confused by the default way of `#lang racket` of printing values, which differs from almost all the other interactive lisp environments. If you choose in DrRacket itself another language, for instance R5RS, you will discover that it prints:

```
> (list 1 2 3 4)
(1 2 3 4)
```

that is, the result of the *operator* `list` applied to the numbers 1 2 3 4 is to produce a list of those numbers, which is exactly the interpretation of `(1 2 3 4)`.

So, the answer to 
[What is ' (apostrophe) in Lisp / Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539144/what-is-apostrophe-in-lisp-scheme) is valid also for your case, and `'anything` is just an abbreviation for `(quote anything)`.

Comment: ok. Thank you for the clarification. But why does `(eval (list + (- 2 13) 11))` evaluate to `0`? Is a function-call nothing more than a list of the function name first followed by its parameters? Because `(eval (list 1 2 3 4))` results in the error `1 is not a procedure`.

Comment: “Is a function-call nothing more than a list of the function name first followed by its parameters?” Almost correct but not completely. In the language what is evaluated is a *form*, that is special list where the first argument is the function. Your first example works since “+” is the name of a function, and the result of `(list + (- 2 13) 11)` is the list `(<the function +> -11 11)` (each argument of `list` is evaluated). In your second example the result of `(list 1 2 3 4)` is the list `(1 2 3 4)`, which is not a form, since `1` is not a function.