# In Lisp (Clojure, Emacs Lisp), what is the difference between list and quote?

Tags: list, clojure, lisp, elisp, quote

From reading introductory material on Lisp, I now consider the following to be identical:

```
(list 1 2 3)

'(1 2 3)
```

However, judging from problems I face when using the quoted form in both Clojure and Emacs Lisp, they are *not* the same. Can you tell me what the difference is?

Comment: They are quit similar in fact take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927115/lisp-quote-work-internally?noredirect=1#comment53680808_32927115)

Answer (score 37):

The primary difference is that `quote` prevents evaluation of the elements, whereas `list` 
does not:

```
user=> '(1 2 (+ 1 2))
(1 2 (+ 1 2))
user=> (list 1 2 (+ 1 2))
(1 2 3)
```

For this reason (among others), it is idiomatic clojure to use a vector when describing a literal collection:

```
user=> [1 2 (+ 1 2)]
[1 2 3]
```

Comment: this answer seems dishonest as it does not mention that `(list 1 2 '(+ 1 2))` is still a list but the third element is not evaluated but it does not express the difference between `'(1 2 (+ 1 2))` and `(list '1 '2 '(+ 1 2))`

Answer (score 13):

In **Common Lisp**, quoted objects are constant literal data. The data is not evaluated. You should not modify this data, as the consequences are undefined. Possible consequences are: modification of shared data, attempt to modify read-only data, an error might be signalled, it might just work, shared data, ...

**Literal lists:**

```
'(1 2 3)
```

Above is a constant list, which will be constructed by the reader and evaluating to itself, because it is quoted. If it appears in Lisp code, a compiler will embed this data somehow in the FASL code.

`(quote (1 2 3))` is another way to write it.

```
(list 1 2 3)
```

this is a call of the Common Lisp function `LIST` with three arguments `1`, `2` and `3`. Each of the arguments will be evaluated. Since they are numbers, they evaluate to themselves. When evaluated the result is a fresh new list `(1 2 3)`.

**Data sharing in compiled code**

Imagine in a Lisp file the following four definitions:

```
(defparameter *list1* (list 1 2 3))
(defparameter *list2* (list 1 2 3))
(defparameter *list3* '(1 2 3))
(defparameter *list4* '(1 2 3))
```

Then we compile and load the file.

**!** `(eq *list3* *list4*)` now may evaluate to either `T` or `NIL` depending on the implementation and compiler settings **!**

Reason: in Common Lisp the Lisp compiler may share structure of literal lists (!) if they are similar. The compiler detects that here the lists are similar and will allocate only one list. Both variables `*list1*` and `*list2*` the will point to this one list.

All other `EQ` (object equality) comparisons of two of the above lists will return `NIL`.

**Notations for some other data structures:**

```
'(1 . 2)            and  (cons 1 2)            ; cons cell

'#(1 2 3)           and  (vector 1 2 3)        ; vector

'#S(FOO :a 1 :b 2)  and (make-foo :a 1 :b 2)   ; structure
```

One is the literal data and the other is a function call that constructs such a data structure.

Answer (score 11):

Quoted lists (e.g. `'(1 2 3)`) should be treated carefully (generally as read-only).  (see SO answers [When to use 'quote in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134887/when-to-use-quote-in-lisp/578365#578365) and [When to use 'quote in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134887/when-to-use-quote-in-lisp/136200#136200)).

`(list 1 2 3)` will "cons" up a fresh list, independent of all others.

You can see an example of a pitfall of using quoted lists in the [manual for `nconc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Rearrangement.html).

And, as you probably know, when you call `'list` - the arguments will obviously be evaluated versus the contents of a quoted list.  And `'quote` takes a single argument, versus `'list`s variable number of arguments.

```
(list (+ 1 2) 3)     -->  (3 3)
(quote ((+ 1 2) 3))  -->  ((+ 1 2) 3)
```

Comment: I liked that you pointed out the difference between their "signatures", the number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Their relation can be analogous to function invocation with 'function name' and `funcall`.

When you have no idea what function you'll get at runtime, you use `funcall`.

When you have no idea what element you may get at runtime, your use `list`.

---

For people like me who get confused because of existence of `backquote` and count it as quote tacitly.

**`backquote` is not `quote`**

It's a reader-macro that expands into `quote`, `list` or others:

```
(macroexpand ''(1 2));=> '(1 2)
(macroexpand '`(1 2));=> '(1 2)
(macroexpand '`(1 ,2));=> (list 1 2)
(macroexpand '`(1 ,@foo));=> (cons 1 foo)
(macroexpand '`(1 ,@foo 2));=> (cons 1 (append foo '(2)))
```