# Mapping logical function

Tags: clojure

I am trying co join two list using map and logical function "and"

```
(map and '(true false true) '(0 1 2))
```

I expect to see

```
(0 false 2)
```

Instead of that

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro:
#'clojure.core/and, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:274:1)
```

occures.

How can I fix it?

Comment: user=> (apply and [true false])
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/and, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:280:1)

user=> (apply + [1 2])
3

Comment: [Use vectors instead of quoted lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896542/in-lisp-clojure-emacs-lisp-what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-quote/3897581#3897581)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the "and" macro into a function

```
(map #(and % %2) '(true false true) '(0 1 2))

Result:(0 false 2)
```

The map function don't let you to use macros as first argument, so this is an easy trick to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

accepted answer is definitely solid, I just wanted to give you an example of converting a macro to a function (mostly for entertaining/learning purposes):

```
(defmacro to-fun [macro]       ;; converting a macro to a function 
  `#(eval (cons '~macro %&)))  ;; e.g. "eval"uated at run time vs. compile time, 
                               ;; and hence can be composed
```

now we can just wrap a(ny) macro with it:

```
(map (to-fun and) [true false true] [0 1 2])
(0 false 2)
```

or:

```
(map (to-fun or) [true false true] [0 1 2])
(true 1 true)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So the problem is the map must get a function and can not work with macro?

Comment: yes. the first argument to a map is a function. what map does, it _[applies](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2516)_ this function to elements in these collections. In order for any function to be _applied_ (read "called"), it needs to have an apply "method" (in Clojure source it is called [applyTo](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/AFn.java#L150)). macro is evaluated at compile time, to usually something other than a "function", and that "somethin other" does not have such a "method" (e.g. can't be _applied_).