# Lisp initialize variable with list

Tags: lisp

I'm learning Lisp. I'm implementing solution to some relatively simple problem. I'm thinking of list that represents initial state of problem like this

```
((0 1) (2 3) (5 4))
```

I want to create variable and assign that list to it. I've tried

```
(let ((initial-state ((0 1) (2 3) (5 4)))))
```

but this won't compile. After that I've tried

```
(let ((initial-state list (list 0 1) (list 2 3) (list 5 4))))
```

this works, but it's too long. Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
(let ((initial-state '((0 1) (2 3) (5 4)))) ...)
```

That single quote is a quote. :)
More about quoting here:

- [When to use 'quote in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134887/when-to-use-quote-in-lisp)
- [Wikipedia article on Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29#Self-evaluating_forms_and_quoting)

Comment: Did you forget some parentheses?

Comment: What lisp are you working in? `let` in Common Lisp doesn't work like that, nor does Scheme's.

Answer (score 5):

```
(let ((initial-state '((0 1) (2 3) (4 5))))
  ...)
```

The `'` expands to `(quote ...)` which basically means "don't evaluate this, just return it to me as a list". It's used to separate data from code (which in lisp are related concepts).