# Confused by Lisp Quoting

Tags: lisp, eval, quote

I have a question concerning evaluation of lists in lisp.

Why is `(a)` and `(+ a 1)` not evaluated,

```
(defun test (a) (+ a 1))
```

just like `(print 4)` is not evaluated here

```
(if (< 1 2) (print 3) (print 4))
```

but `(print (+ 2 3))` is evaluated here

```
(test (print (+ 2 3)))
```

Does it have something to do with them being standard library functions? Is it possible for me to define functions like that in my lisp program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use 'quote in Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134887/when-to-use-quote-in-lisp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you probably know, Lisp compound forms are generally processed from the outside in. You must look at the symbol in the first position of the outermost nesting to understand a form. That symbol completely determines the meaning of the form. The following expressions all contain `(b c)` with completely different meaning; therefore, we cannot understand them by analyzing the `(b c)` part first:

```
;; Common Lisp: define a class A derived from B and C
(defclass a (b c) ())

;; Common Lisp: define a function of two arguments
(defun a (b c) ())

;; add A to the result of calling function B on variable C:
(+ a (b c))
```

Traditionally, Lisp dialects have divided forms into operator forms and function call forms. An operator form has a completely arbitrary meaning, determined by the piece of code which compiles or interprets that functions (e.g. the evaluation simply recurses over all of the function call's argument forms, and the resulting values are passed to the function).

From the early history, Lisp has allowed users to write their own operators. There existed two approaches to this: interpretive operators (historically known as `fexprs`) and compiling operators known as macros. Both hinge around the idea of a function which receives the unevaluated form as an argument, so that it can implement a custom strategy, thereby extending the evaluation model with new behaviors.

A `fexpr` type operator is simply handed the form at run-time, along with an environment object with which it can look up the values of variables and such. That operator then walks the form and implements the behavior.

A macro operator is handed the form at macro-expansion time (which usually happens when top-level forms are read, just before they are evaluated or compiled). Its job is not to interpret the form's behavior, but instead to translate it by generating code. I.e. a macro is a mini compiler. (Generated code can contain more macro calls; the macro expander will take care of that, ensuring that all macro calls are decimated.)

The `fexpr` approach fell out of favor, most likely because it is inefficient. It basically makes compilation impossible, whereas Lisp hackers valued compilation. (Lisp was already a compiled language from as early as circa 1960.) The `fexpr` approach is also hostile toward lexical environments; it requires the `fexpr`, which is a function, to be able to peer into the variable binding environment of the form in which its invoked, which is a kind of encapsulation violation that is not allowed by lexical scopes.

Macro writing is slightly more difficult, and in some ways less flexible than fexprs, but support for macro writing improved in Lisp through the 1960's into the 70's to make it close to as easy as possible. Macro originally had receive the whole form and then have to parse it themselves. The macro-defining system developed into something that provides macro functions with arguments that receive the broken-down syntax in easily digestible pieces, including some nested aspects of the syntax. The backquote syntax for writing code templates was also developed, making it much easier to express code generation.

So to answer your question, how can I write forms like that myself? For instance if:

```
;; Imitation of old-fashioned technique: receive the whole form,
;; extract parts from it and return the translation.
;; Common Lisp defmacro supports this via the &whole keyword
;; in macro lambda lists which lets us have access to the whole form.
;;
;; (Because we are using defmacro, we need to declare arguments "an co &optional al",
;; to make this a three argument macro with an optional third argument, but
;; we don't use those arguments. In ancient lisps, they would not appear:
;; a macro would be a one-argument function, and would have to check the number
;; of arguments itself, to flag bad syntax like (my-if 42) or (my-if).)
;;
(defmacro my-if (&whole if-form an co &optional al)
  (let ((antecedent (second if-form))   ;; extract pieces ourselves
        (consequent (third if-form))    ;; from whole (my-if ...) form
        (alternative (fourth if-form)))
    (list 'cond (list antecedent consequent) (list t alternative))))

;; "Modern" version. Use the parsed arguments, and also take advantage of
;; backquote syntax to write the COND with a syntax that looks like the code.
(defmacro my-if (antecedent consequent &optional alternative)
   `(cond (,antecedent ,consequent) (t ,alternative))))
```

This is a fitting example because originally Lisp only had `cond`. There was no `if` in McCarthy's Lisp. That "syntactic sugar" was invented later, probably as a macro expanding to `cond`, just like `my-if` above.

Answer (score 6):

`if` and `defun` are macros.  Macros expand a form into a longer piece of code.  At expansion time, none of the macro's arguments are evaluated.

When you try to write a function, but struggle because you need to implement a custom evaluation strategy, its a strong signal that you should be writing a macro instead.

Disclaimer: Depending on what kind of lisp you are using, `if` and `defun` might technically be called "special forms" and not macros, but the concept of delayed evaluation still applies.

Answer (score 1):

Lisp consists of a model of evaluation of forms. Different Lisp dialects have different rules for those.

Let's look at Common Lisp.

- data evaluates to itself
- a function form is evaluated by calling the function on the evaluated arguments
- special forms are evaluated according to rules defined for each special operator. The Common Lisp standard lists all of those, defines what they do in an informal way and there is no way to define new special operators by the user.
- macros forms are transformed, the result is evaluated

How IF, DEFUN etc. works and what they evaluated, when it is doen and what is not evaluated is defined in the Common Lisp standard.