# symbols handling: cannot compare for identity

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, equality, quote

I don't get why

```
(setq a_sym 'abc)
(print (eq a_sym 'abc))

(print (eq 'x 'x))
(print (eq (first '('x 2 3)) 'x))
```

prints

```
T 
T 
NIL
```

Why the symbol `'x` in the third statement is handled differently than second ? And, down to earth, how to compare them for identity ?

Comment: Your use of `print` indicates that you use "batch" - you might want to use the REPL instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15708911/850781

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [`trace`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_tracec.htm) what you are comparing, you will see your mistake right away:

```
[1]> (eq (first '('x 2 3)) 'x)
NIL
[2]> (trace eq)

** - Continuable Error
TRACE(EQ): #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP> is locked
If you continue (by typing 'continue'): Ignore the lock and proceed
The following restarts are also available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
Break 1 [3]> :c
WARNING: TRACE: redefining function EQ in top-level, was defined in C
;; Tracing function EQ.
(EQ)
[4]> (eq (first '('x 2 3)) 'x)
1. Trace: (EQ ''X 'X)  ;    <=======    note 1
1. Trace: EQ ==> NIL
NIL
[5]> (eq (first '(x 2 3)) 'x)
1. Trace: (EQ 'X 'X)   ;    <=======    note 2
1. Trace: EQ ==> T
T
```

IOW, you are "overquoting" your `x`: when you type `'x`, it's the same as `(quote x)` so, you are checking for equality of symbol `x` and list `(quote x)` and, of course, getting `nil`.

### Notes:

1. `(eq ''x 'x)`: since `eq` is a function, its arguments are evaluated and we are comparing `'x == (quote x)` with `x` and getting `nil`.
2. `(eq 'x 'x)`: for the same reason, we are comparing `x` with `x` and getting `t`.

### Related:

1. [Lisp quote work internally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32927115/850781)
2. [Confused by Lisp Quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9843011/850781)
3. [When to use 'quote in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134887/850781)
4. [Lisp: quoting a list of symbols' values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20728980/850781)

Comment: you are welcome! as an exercise, you might want to `(trace first)` and see what happens.

Comment: Well, I tried `(step ...)`. The level of details and lacking of experience was stressing me... when I hit :n, for instance, I'm unable to predict the debugger answer. I'll try `(trace ...)`, thanks again

Comment: lisp takes time to get used to, but its power and beauty are unsurpassable! :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Syntax and reading**

You wrote:

> symbol `'x`

Note that `'x` is not a symbol. It's a quote character in front of a symbol. The quote character has a special meaning in s-expressions: read the next item and enclose it in `(quote ...)`.

Thus `'x` is really the list `(quote x)`.

```
CL-USER 9 > (read-from-string "'x")
(QUOTE X)
2
```

**Evaluation**

A quoted object is not evaluated. The `quote` is a *special operator*, which means it is built-in syntax/semantics in Common Lisp and not a function and not a macro. The evaluator returns the quoted object as such:

```
CL-USER 10 > (quote x)
X
```

**Your example**

```
(eq (first (quote ((quote x) 2 3))) (quote x))
```

Let's evaluate the first part:

```
CL-USER 13 > (first (quote ((quote x) 2 3)))
(QUOTE X)
```

The result is the list `(quote x)`.

Let's evaluate the second part:

```
CL-USER 14 > 'x
X
```

So the result is the symbol `x`.

`x` and `(quote x)` are not *eq*.

**Evaluation and Quoting**

```
'('x 2 3)
```

What would be the purpose of the second quote in the list?

The first quote already means that the *WHOLE* following data structure is not to be evaluated. Thus it is not necessary to quote a symbol inside to prevent its evaluation. If a list is quoted, none of its sublists or subelements are evaluated.

**Summary**

The quote is not part of the symbol. It is a built-in *special operator* used to prevent evaluation.