# Lisp: quoting a list of symbols' values

Tags: lisp, elisp, quote

How do I create a quoted list in Lisp that uses the symbols' values in the list, rather than the symbols themselves? For example, take two variables `foo` and `bar`, `foo` = `"hello"` and `bar` = `"world"`. How do I get a list that contains `"hello" "world"` from these two variables. The best thing I can think of is this:

```
;; This is Emacs Lisp
(let ((foo "hello")
      (bar "world"))
  (message (prin1-to-string '(foo bar)))
;; prints "(foo bar)"
```

But this is wrong. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: in Common Lisp, also: ``(let (...) (msg `(foo ,foo bar ,bar)))``. Automatically translated into ``(let (...) (msg (list 'foo foo 'bar bar)))``.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use 'quote in Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134887/when-to-use-quote-in-lisp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, further experimentation revealed that the answer is `(list foo bar)`.

```
(let ((foo "hello")
      (bar "world"))
  (message (prin1-to-string (list foo bar)))
;; prints '("hello" "world")'
```

**EDIT**: Another way of achieving this is using `` `(,foo ,bar) ``

```
(let ((foo "hello")
      (bar "world"))
  (message (prin1-to-string `(,foo ,bar)))
;; prints '("hello" "world")'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather strange question since if you want the value of `foo` and `bar` you are not suppose to quote it. Using only primitives you make such list:

```
(let ((foo "hello")
      (bar "world"))
  (cons foo (cons bar nil))) ; ==> ("hello" "world")
```

There is a function called [`list`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_list_.htm) that does the cons for you, thus `(list foo bar 'foo 'bar)` does the same as `(cons foo (cons bar (cons 'foo (cons 'bar nil))))` ==> `("hello" "world" foo bar)` in the same scope as the code above.

With [quasiquoting (backquoting)](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm) you can mix constants so that `` `(,foo ,bar foo bar) `` is the equivalent, but be aware that constant tails, like `'(foo bar)` in my example, get reused.