# Strange results using quote, reversing a list with all sublists recursively

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, common-lisp, quote

I wrote a code to reverse a list and all its sublists recursively :

```
(defun rev1( list final )
    ( if ( eq list () )
       final
       ( if ( atom ( car list ) )
           ( rev1( cdr list ) ( cons ( car list ) final ) )
           ( rev1( cdr list ) ( cons ( rev1( car list ) () ) final ) ))))

(defun rev(list)
   ( rev1 list () ) )
```

The problem is that if I call the function with : `( rev '( 1 2 '( 3 2 1 ) 3 ) )` the expected output should be `(3 (1 2 3) 2 1)` but instead of this what I get is : `(3 ((1 2 3) QUOTE) 2 1)` and I do not understand why. Could anyone explain me where's the problem?

Comment: http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use 'quote in Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134887/when-to-use-quote-in-lisp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'` character is a reader macro, i.e. the Lisp reader will expand it into a call to [`quote`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_quote.htm). The [CLHS entry on `quote`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_quote.htm) gives the following evaluation examples:

```
'a  => A
''a => (QUOTE A)
```

Hence:

```
(rev (list 'a))  =>     (A)
(rev (list ''a)) =>     ((A QUOTE))
(rev ''a)        =>     (A QUOTE)
(rev '(a))       =>     (A)
(rev '('a))      =>     ((A QUOTE))
```