# Lisp - Make a list with variable value

Tags: lisp, quote

I save the variable value `(setf num (+ 4 5))` like this and 
I save the `(setf str '("Hello"))`.

And then I want make a list like this `(setq v '(num str))`.
However because of the single quote, it doesn't recognize it as a string and not working as expected.

how can i make a list with variable value?

Comment: Use [`list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_list_.htm) or [`cons`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/f_cons.htm)

Comment: (list num str) or cons      it doesn't work ..  how to use this function?

Comment: `(list var1 var2)` is the same as `(cons var1 (cons var2 '()))`. What doesn't work?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask you further.
but one more i want to ask question.

i making this function.

(f 3 4)  (sum = 7)
(f 'a 'b)  (not num!)

i try to (format nil "sum = ~D." x)
but, my problem is how can i make use formatting in list?

Comment: You can just quote the elements you want to be literal: `(list 'sim '= 7)`. IN place of 7 you can just put a variable or an expression.

Comment: Thank you .  It was solved because of you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use 'quote in Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134887/when-to-use-quote-in-lisp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [special operator](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababa.htm) [quote](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm) prevents evaluation of your variables.

You need to call a [*function*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababc.htm) (which evaluates its arguments), e.g., [`list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/a_list.htm):

```
(list num str)
==> (9 "Hello")
```

Comment: Thank you. But could you please look at my comments on the above question?

Comment: You are welcome. You should ask a separate question for each issue instead of starting a comment conversation.