# How are arguments passed into functions in Elisp?

Tags: lisp, parameter-passing, elisp

Coming from a C++ background, I'm trying to figure out how arguments are passed into methods in Elisp.  While I acknowledge that maybe the wording could be different, I'm wondering if it is closer to the C++ idea of passing by reference or passing by value?  If I alter the parameter in the method itself, will it alter the parameter that was passed in in the function call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All Lisps ([Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Forms.html), [Common Lisp](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababc.htm)) pass parameters by value, always:

```
(defparameter x 42)  ; defconst in Emacs Lisp
(defun test (x)
  (setq x 10))
(test x)
==> 10
x
==> 42
```

Note, however, that some values are actually *pointers* (or, rather, objects with components), so a function can modify their *content* by side effects:

```
(defparameter x (list 1 2))
(defun test (x)
  (setf (first x) 42
        (second x) 24
        x 17))
(test x)
==> 17
x
==> (42 24)
```

**PS1**. Cf. [When to use ' (or quote) in Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134887/850781) -- "quoted arguments" are evaluated too: the evaluation strips the quote.

**PS2**. Cf. [`add-to-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html) - it accepts a *symbol* (variable name) and modifies its value. This only works for global dynamic variables, *not* for lexical variables. Not a very good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in Emacs Lisp, there is no such thing like passing a argument by value or by reference, not to mention pointer. But all arguments passed to function will be evaluated in advance except those have a `'` prefix. Always remember When you set a variable, you always just create symbol with a value.[[1]](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variables.html)

**So if you want to modify a variable's value in a function, all you need to do is modifying the value of that variable's symbol in that function.**

Check my code bellow.

```
(defvar my-val 1)

(defun my-func-value (val)
  (setq val 2))

(defun my-func-symbol (sym)
  ;; NOTE! using set instead of setq,
  ;; casue we want symbol "my-val" be evaluated from "sym" here
  (set sym 2))

(my-func-value my-val) ; evaluate my-val before passed into function
(message "my-val: %s" my-val) ; my-val: 1

(my-func-symbol 'my-val) ; pass my-val symbol directly into function
(message "my-val: %s" my-val) ; my-val: 2
```

**Note! If the variable is a lexically-bound variable[[2]](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html), it's still true that you can modified the symbol's value but not the value in the lexical environment.**

Here is the code:

```
(let ((my-lexical-var 1))
  (my-func-symbol 'my-lexical-var)
  ;; evaluate from lexical environment
  (message "my-lexical-var: %s" my-lexical-var) ; my-lexical-var: 1
  ;; evaluate from the symbol
  (message "symbol my-lexical-var: %s" (symbol-value 'my-lexical-var))
  ; symbol my-lexical-var: 2
```

Comment: All function arguments are always evaluated. `'` is not a prefix, but a reader macro to abbreviate the [quote form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134887/850781), which evaluates to its second term.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a quote form, but also like a prefix to that variable. Anyway you are missing the point. Did you check out my code snipe above, that's what I try to point out.@sds

Comment: Note that if the variable has *lexical* scope (which isn't the case here), then it's not true that passing the variable's symbol allows you to modify the variable's value with `set` (because the lexical value and the symbol's value are not the same thing).