# how to set something from existing lists in Common Lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I was wondering can we set a list from an already existing list?

```
(setq example1 '(1 2 3))
(setq example2 '((caddr example1) (cadr example1) (car example1)))
```

I know the way I've written it won't achieve the desired result but is there anyway to achieve that result?And how?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Here is a basic Lisp introduction - you can download a PDF: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> can we set a list from an already existing list?

Sure you can, but I think you are still confused about when quote [should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134887/when-to-use-or-quote-in-lisp). Nothing inside a quoted expression is evaluated.

In order to set the list `example2` with the elements of `example1` would be enough to construct a list with that elements, such as:

```
(setq example2 (list (caddr example1) (cadr example1) (car example1)))
```

Comment: Thank you!I am new to lisp so yes I don't know when to use it i'm just playing around with stuff trying to get the hang of it so far I think I have got the hang of it of some the stuff.And can you recommend more documentation for stuff like this?Thanks again!

Comment: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/common-lisp.html This is a good reference point.

Comment: @jakHunter I would add to that the excellent Gigamonkeys book on Practical Common Lisp, which can be viewed for free online (http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/).

Comment: Thanks but I already know those 2 sites aren't there any other?