# clisp: variable has no value

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to make user-program which extract elements `a` which have element `b` (given by parameter) as pair in list.

Like, if I give `c` as parameter and list `((c a) (c b) (d f) (d g))`,
result should be `'a' 'b'`;

So I define a function as below,

```
(defun myr (b a) (if (= CAAR(a) b) CDAR(a) 'nope myr(b CDR(a))));
```

and call like this

```
myr(b ((b a) (b c) (a d) (a f)))
```

But result is like `variable myr has no value`

Its my first time in Lisp, So just tell me what keyword should I search for will be great help for me.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *really* need to start with a good lisp book, e.g., [PCL](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) or [ACL](http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html).
You will save yourself a lot of time.

Lisp syntax is different from C. 
In C, you call a function `f` with arguments `х` and `y` like this: `f(x,y)`.
In Lisp, you do it like this: `(f x y)`.

When you invoke your function `myr(...)`, you put the symbol `myr` in the *variable* position, not *function* position, which causes the error you reported.

You also need to use [`quote`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134887/850781) as appropriate.