# What does the ' represent in '+ in racket?

Tags: syntax, racket

I have been banging around on google and drRacket trying to understand what the apostrophe `'` before a procedure means in racket and how I could remove it. What I'm trying to do is take a + from inside a list i.e. `'(+ 1 2)`. However, every time I do something like `(first x)` (where x is the list in the example) I receive '+ instead of just + (notice the apostrophe). How can I remove the apostrophe and what is its purpose?

Comment: The answers to this question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/134887/371228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'` apostrophe, pronounced `quote`, mean that the stuff inside will be interpreted as data for an s-expression, not evaluated as code.

`'x`, `'hello`, and `'+` are all symbols, which are like strings with unique-identity properties. They contain only text, not "meaning", so the `'+` symbol does not contain a reference to the `+` function.

If you use parentheses under a `'` quote, it will create a list with all the elements also `'` quoted. In other words, `'(x y z)` is equivalent to `(list 'x 'y 'z)`. You can think of this as quote "distributing itself" over all the elements inside it.

In your case, `'(+ 1 2)` is equivalent to `(list '+ '1 '2)`, which is the same as `(list '+ 1 2)` because numbers are already literal data.

In most cases, the best way to get rid of a `'` quote is to not add one on the outside in the first place. Instead of `'(+ 1 2)` you could use `list`: `(list + 1 2)`, or the more advanced forms `` ` `` quasiquote and `,` unquote: `` `(,+ 1 2) ``. In either of these cases, the `+` never gets put under a quote in the first place. It never becomes a symbol like `'+`. The `+` outside of any quote has meaning as the addition function.

In other cases, you can't avoid having the symbol `'+` because it comes from intrinsically textual data. In this case you can assign meaning to it with an interpreter. Somewhere in that interpreter you might want code like this

```
(match sym ['+ +] ['- -] ['* *] ['/ /] [_ (error "unrecognized symbol")])
```

Something is needed to assign meaning *externally*, because the symbol `'+` does not have that meaning internally. You can either define the interpreter yourself or <sub><sup>use an existing one such as eval</sup></sub>, as long as all the meanings in the interpreter correspond exactly to what you intend.