# Can't pass variable to secure-hash

Tags: elisp

Why does secure-hash fail when I use a variable on the second call?  Emacs 27.1, 27.2 and 26.3

```
(setq mytext "test")
(message (secure-hash 'sha256' mytext))
(message (secure-hash 'sha256' "test"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra [quote `'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134887/850781) before `mytext` that prevents evaluation of the `mytext` variable.

The following works just fine:

```lisp
(let ((mytext "test"))
  (secure-hash 'sha256 mytext))
==> "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08"
(secure-hash 'sha256 "test")
==> "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08"
```

PS. If you are new to Lisp and this was not just a typo, you will greatly benefit from reading ["An Introduction to Programming in Emacs
Lisp"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html).
The best way to do it is in Emacs: <kbd>C-h i m intro TAB RET</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That worked out.  I'm not exactly new to lisp but I do bumble around in it because I rarely program in it.