# LISP - Iterate through an array - MAPCAR

Tags: arrays, iteration, lisp, common-lisp

I have found a lot of resources on SO and books but none of them were understandable (enough) for me.
I'm trying to iterate through an array with LISP.

Here is how i create my array:

```
(setf question-array
      (make-array '(8 2)
                  :initial-contents
                  '((1 "How old are you:")
                    (2 "Whats your name:")
                    ...)))
```

But after some research it looks like i should use:

```
(mapcar (lambda (x)
          (print))
        '(question-array))
```

But it only print:

```
QUESTION-ARRAY
```

I would like to print each question. So i guess #'second ?
What am i missing ?

(More context: My goal is to ask questions to users and store answers somehow to count point at the end.)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Lispers read Lisp using indentation, so you would make our (and yours!) lives much easier if you indented your code properly (as I now did). You can use Emacs to indent your code automatically.

Comment: Do you insist on using a 2d array? I would use a 1d list or vector (only questions), but maybe you have some reason to include indices in your array - are they important somehow?

Comment: Also, could you add more information about your specific use case? "iterate through data and print" is quite general (`loop`, `dolist`, `dotimes`,...), but "ask questions to users and store answers somehow to count point at the end" sounds more like `loop` + `collect`.

Comment: An example with loop here: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/iteration.html#loop-across use "across"

Comment: An almost-certainly-better approach would be to have a list (not array) of questions, and use `mapcar` to construct another list of answers for each question.

Answer (score 7):

1. [`mapcar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm) only works on [`list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_list.htm)s, not [`vector`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_vector.htm)s
2. You are not passing `x` to [`print`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) in your [`lambda`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_lambda.htm)
3. You are [quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134887/850781) `(question-array)` so the function is not called - but it is not a function, it is a variable!

To iterate over a [`vector`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_vector.htm) use [`map`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map.htm):

```
(setq question-vector (vector "question 1" "question 2" ...))
(map nil #'print question-vector)
```

or [`dotimes`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dotime.htm):

```
(dotimes (i (length question-vector))
  (print (aref question-vector i)))
```

or [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm):

```
(loop for q across question-vector
  do (print q))
```

Your `question-array` is actually a 2-dimensional [`array`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_array.htm) and not a [`vector`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_vector.htm) (so it is not a [`sequence`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_seq.htm), and [`map`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map.htm) cannot help you).

Instead, you can do

```
(dotimes (i (array-dimension question-array 0))
  (print (aref question-array i 1)))
```