# How to use dynamic variables as elements of an array

Tags: arrays, common-lisp

I would like to use an array or list to store dynamic variables for later retrieval via an index. So if I have:

```lisp
(defparameter *foo* '(1 2 3))
(defparameter *bar* '(3 4 5))
(defparameter *baz*
  (make-array 2 :initial-contents '(*foo* *bar*)))
```

I would like to retrieve `*foo*` by calling `(aref *baz* 0)` and have this return `'(1 2 3)`

Of course, this doesn't work and the `*foo*` stored in `*baz*` isn't even the special variable I defined at top-level, as shown when I try to do `(elt (aref *baz* 0) 1)` which only returns an error and not the value 2. Let me say I am new to Common Lisp and I don't even know how to describe this question in a way that helped me in searching through CLHS, etc. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between a symbol (which is a data type in Lisp) and its value. The symbol exists as an object. The value of a symbol is either the result of an evaluation or can be retrieved by accessing the symbol value. Lisp is one of the few languages where a symbol is a first class datatype and which has also a value which can be set and bound.

```
> '*foo*
*foo*       ; the symbol *foo* itself

> *foo*
(1 2 3)     ; the value of the symbol *foo* -> this list

> (eval '*foo*)
(1 2 3)     ; the value of the symbol *foo* -> this list


> (symbol-value '*foo*)
(1 2 3)     ; the value of the symbol *foo* -> this list
```

One can retrieve the value of a symbol with the function `symbol-value`:

```
(symbol-value '*foo*)

(let ((symbol '*foo*))
  (symbol-value symbol))
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read [When to use ' (or quote) in Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134887/when-to-use-or-quote-in-lisp) and CLHS [quote entry](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/s_quote.htm) for a comprehensive explanation.

I will just focus on two problems in your code:

**Usage of quote**

Look at `'(*foo* *bar*)`. [`quote`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/s_quote.htm) stops the evaluation of these two symbols, so result of this expression will be a list with two symbols, `*foo*` and `*bar*`.

Compare that with `(list *foo* *bar*)`- during evaluation, symbols `*foo*` and `*bar*` are evaluated to their values, so the result will be `'((1 2 3) (3 4 5))`.

**Usage of quoted lists**

As [CLHS quote entry](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/s_quote.htm) says:

> The consequences are undefined if literal objects (including quoted
> objects) are destructively modified.

If you want to modify your lists later, you should create them with `list` or another function.

So, your code should look like this:

```
(defparameter *foo* (list 1 2 3))
(defparameter *bar* (list 3 4 5))
(defparameter *baz*
  (make-array 2 :initial-contents (list *foo* *bar*)))
```

I would also consider using 2d array, so you can combine `elt` + `aref` into one `(aref *baz* 0 0)`, but that depends on the exact problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: To be clear: using the `quote` form is fine for specifying the initial contents in the call to `make-array` even if `*baz*` will be modified later since `*baz*` is bound to the new array and not the initial contents list.